# Entropy - does Heat Death occur in a closed system

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

Does heat death occur in a closed system? (Assuming you can theoretically have some sort of "closed system".

Comment: FWIW: here's some psychologists explaining the dress color perception: http://redd.it/2xbfxp

Comment: Not necessarily in a closed system because heat can be exchanged, but in an isolated system yes. And [Wired](http://www.wired.com/2015/02/science-one-agrees-color-dress/) had an article on the dress.

Comment: The dress is in a superposition of all four.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a degree to which this is just terminology, but in cosmology a distinction is somtimes made between the Heat Death and the Big Freeze. The Big Freeze is the point at which the universe reaches absolute zero, while the Heat Death is the point at which the entire universe has a constant temperature. These are not necessarily the same thing, because a de Sitter universe possesses a cosmological horizon and this will emit Hawking radiation. That means a de Sitter universe will never cool to absolute zero - only to the temperature of the Hawking radiation. However the distinction I make here is far from standard and you'll see the two terms being used interchangeably.

The point of all this is that a closed system is never going to cool to absolute zero because obviously if it's closed heat can't escape from it. However it can attain a state of uniform temperature. So it can attain a state of Heat Death, but only for a subset of commonly used meanings of the term *Heat Death*.

Comment: Interesting insight.. so my only other question is, does entropy increase in a closed system? I'm aware that you said it will reach "heat death" (aka consistent temperature), just to be clear "consistent" means evenly distribute and lowest value obtainable (because of entropy increasing)?

Comment: Yes, the entropy will increase in a closed system up to some maximum value determined by the construction of the system. By *uniform* temperature I mean that the temperature is the same everywhere in the system.

Comment: Entropy can decrease in a closed system sometime,for example you can decrease the entropy of your house using refrigerator but doing that you finally increase the entropy of the system(house) plus the sorrounding(entropy of the universe).we cannot take the whole universe as a system,there must be a sorrounding.